# Drop in SERP after migrating to a new server

Tags: google-search

Everthing was going fine with my website untill I switched to a new server.

On the first day, I started to see a drop in SERP and delay of indexing of new posts. Nothing else has changed except the server migeration.

How could they be related?

Comment: Check the IP address of the server for issues associated with spam, hacking, phishing, etc. Host quality is a really important factor.

Comment: How can I check for that?

Comment: Try here: https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check for the new server response time.

Migration really doesn't effect the SERP results, but Server change can introduce certain changes to crawler.

Have you resubmitted for indexing of website?

To resubmit, use **fetch by google** and type your website name.

Also, regenerate a new *sitemap.xml* and submit it to the search console.

Comment: Response time is fine, and there's no server errors in Search Console.

How would I resubmit?

Comment: Use fetch by Google from Google Search Console.